# How to manage user session in win forms?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, session, ado.net

I have tried to manage user session, but the issue is I can not access other attributes in the database as they are not in the object.

```
 Teacher t = new Teacher
                {

                    t_email = textBox_Login_Email.Text,
                    t_password = textBox_Login_Pass.Text,

                };
```

Other attributes are t_id and t_name. I can only access these two using the following code

```
session.Instance.user.t_email
session.Instance.user.t_password
```

I need to get Teacher's id which is t_id from the database.
I am storing the object "t" in the session object using

```
session.Instance.user = t;
```

Below is the code for  my session class and login class
session.cs

```
public class session
    {
        #region Define as Singleton
        private static session _Instance;
        public static session Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if(_Instance == null)
                {
                    _Instance = new session();
                }

                return (_Instance);
            }
        }

        private session()
        {

        }
        #endregion

        public Teacher user { get; set; }

        public bool isLoggedIn
        {
            get
            {
                if (user != null)
                    return true;
                else return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

login.cs

```
namespace TestBoardAdmin
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (examEntities obj = new examEntities())
            {
                Teacher t = new Teacher
                {

                    t_email = textBox_Login_Email.Text,
                    t_password = textBox_Login_Pass.Text,

                };



                //var x = obj.Teachers.Where(a => a.t_email == t.t_email).Select(a => new { a.t_id });
                var y = obj.Teachers.Where(a => a.t_email == t.t_email && a.t_password == t.t_password);
                if (y.Count() > 0)
                {


                    MessageBox.Show("Logged In succesfully");
                    textBox_Login_Email.Clear();
                    textBox_Login_Pass.Clear();
                    //this.Close();

                    session.Instance.user = t;
                    Chose_Action chose_action = new Chose_Action();
                    chose_action.Show();
                    //return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    //ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Wrong Email or Password";
                    //return 0;
                    MessageBox.Show("Email or Password Incorrect");
                    //textBox_Login_Email.Clear();
                    textBox_Login_Pass.Clear();
                }
            }

        }

        private void textBox_Login_Email_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox_Login_Pass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I actually want to store the corresponding t_id in another table when the user adds in the database, the database will also add the id of the user who added something in the database. So, for that I want to get t_id of the corresponding user session.

I have used ado.net and Linq in this project.

Comment: You should do `t = obj.Teachers.Where(....). FirstOrDefault();` and then check `if(t != null)`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya can you describe it more?

Comment: Replace `var y = obj.Teachers.Where(.....` line of code with `t = obj.Teachers.Where(a => a.t_email == t.t_email && a.t_password == t.t_password).FirstOrDefault();` and replace `if (y.Count() > 0)` with `if(t != null)`

Comment: Solved the issue @ChetanRanpariya Thank you